# How to get rid of our $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, refactoring

Our project has some data stored in a single `$_SESSION['app']`. There is one "main" object that contains about 10 public instances of other objects that could be used within the code. In fact only one of them is used regularly ( `$_SESSION['app']->login->getuserId()` ) and two of them are used just 4-5 times in total.

Since we have created a RESTful API aside from our project we want to use some of our projects' features within the API and therefor need to get rid of the session that is used in lots of methods in almost all objects and on the long run we want to switch to RESTful communication between Client and Server completely.

Since we are a small team we can't afford to refactor all code at once but need to do it step by step without breaking the code in the meantime.

My first attempt is transforming the session-object into a singleton like this:

```
class Main {

  private static $main = null;

  public static function getInstance() {
    self::$main = $_SESSION['app'] ?? self::$main ?? new Main();
    return self::$main;
  }

  public function __construct {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This way for some time, we could leave the instantiation of $_SESSION['app'] as it is and later completely remove the session in one small step of work. My attempt works okay so far but it only shifts the conceptual problem I we have with the `Main` class.

Also I've read that using the Singleton Pattern is a bad idea in most cases and understand the arguments for that opinion. In our project we don't use Unit testing yet but I want to use that soon for my code at least.

*So what would be a better and more reliable way to get rid of our `$_SESSION`-variable and handle data like the `userID` in a way that it could be accessed from everywhere so that in the end we can have a RESTful authentication instead of a session?*

Comment: Couldn't you just continue using it as is - but instead of populating the array from the session you fetch whatever you need from the authenticated user (ie using a jwt)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way, how I see that:

If we imagine for a second that you have a system of your dream with RESTful API, then probably the communication between clients and a sever will rely on "access_token" solution, what means there will be a class or classes that will authorize a user and check user permissions.

This solution somehow will be used during the bootstrapping process, but should be preferably isolated and decoupled and thus implemented through a dependency injection paradigm. That will give you right out of the box an ability to replace one implementation with another (awesome unit testing bonus, eh!)

First implementation could, however, be totally built on top of the current sessions. To make it easy you can start with a "plain" replace `$_SESSION['app']` with something like `Di::getDefault()->getSession()->get('app')` or may be `Di::getDefault()->getAuthorizedUser()->getApp()` and then just constantly grow your functionality on top of that.

Comment: I don't fully understand "dependency injection" yet. is there anything more to it than: "Every class should get access to their dependencies via an argument and every dependency should be accessed through an interface." ?